# Linux: Unzip archive and rename contents to archive name followed by an incrementing number

Tags: linux, command-line, unzip, mv

I have several hundred .zip files sitting in a directory named /zip. All of the .zip files have a unique naming convention. For example: 123456_123456.zip

What I am trying to accomplish via command line for all of the .zip files:

1. Unzip each archive. (Example 123456_123456.zip etc.)
2. Rename each file that gets unzipped to the archive name followed by a incrementing number and with the files original extension. Example: Archive Contents = TEST123.pdf, TEST321.csv --> 123456_123456_1.pdf, 123456_123456_2.csv
3. The incrementing number should reset to 0 as the script moves onto another archive.

Here is what I have so far.

```
for z in *.zip;
do 
num=0; 
sudo unzip -njB "$z"; 
sudo mv -b "$(unzip -Z1 $z)" "${z%%.*}_$((++num)).$(unzip -Z1 $z | awk -F'[.]' '{print $2}')";
done
```

This seems to work except for handling archives that have multiple files in them.
When the script encounters an archive that contains multiple files it throws an error such as mv:cannot stat 'TEST123.pdf\nTEST321.csv':No such file or directory.

Any suggestions for getting the script to handle multiple files within an archive?

Comment: *Example: Archive Contents = TEST123.pdf, TEST321.csv --> 123456_123456_1.pdf, 123456_123456_2.csv* Seems odd - why would you want to trash the original file names?

Comment: @g00se the original file names in the archives are meaningless in this case...the archive name being assigned to the archive contents is what will then give the files a meaningful name...at least in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You need a second for loop for the extracted contents. (This is assuming no subdirs, assuming there are no files or dirs with `tmp-` prefix in that folder - other option, tmpdir - but not really portable)

```
for z in *.zip
do 
  num=0; 
  sudo unzip -njB "$z" -d tmp-$(basename ${z} zip)
  pushd "tmp-$(basename ${z} zip)"
  for a in *
  do 
    sudo mv -b "$(unzip -Z1 $a)" "${a%%.*}_$((++num)).$(unzip -Z1 $a | awk - F'[.]' '{print $2}')";
  done
  sudo rm -r "tmp-$(basename ${z} zip)"
  popd
done
```